# How to write the desired first line on each sheet word document C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-automation

How can I insert text into a Word document (use C# Interop) so that the first line of each sheet has an inscription, for example "continuation of the table"? I suppose to do it like this...

Find the lines of each of the pages and on each page find the first line and insert. Maybe it can be done differently ... more gracefully. But even with my approach, not all lines are displayed.

```
var rng = docDocument.Range();
int LineCount = rng.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticLines);

try
{
    for (int ii = 1; ii < LineCount; ii++)
    {
        CurrentPageNumber = (Convert.ToInt32(ii.ToString()));
        NextPageNumber = (Convert.ToInt32((ii + 1).ToString()));

        // Get start position of current page
        Start = oWord.Selection.GoTo(ref What, ref Which, ref CurrentPageNumber, ref Miss).Start;

        // Get end position of current page
        End = oWord.Selection.GoTo(ref What, ref Which, ref NextPageNumber, ref Miss).End;

        var rng_page = docDocument.Range(Start, End);
        string textLine = rng_page.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(textLine);

        var line_rng = docDocument.Range(unit);
        string textline_line = line_rng.Text;
        //Console.WriteLine(textline_line);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _ = ex.Message;
}
```

It looks like something has moved...
But each new page has one or two new lines. In addition, since the file being edited has a large number of sheets, which entails additional lines and additional sheets, and this function is no longer performed on these sheets.

```
for (int Index = 2; Index <= PagesCount; Index++)
{
    CurrentPageNumber = (Convert.ToInt32(Index.ToString()));
    Word.Range range1 = docDocument.GoTo(ref objWhat, ref objWhich, CurrentPageNumber, ref Miss);
    Word.Range range2 = range1.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine);
    object objStart = range1.Start;
    object objEnd = range2.End;
    //string str = docDocument.Range(ref objStart, ref objEnd).Text;
    range1.InsertParagraph();
    range1.Text = "new_TEXT_new_TXET\n";

}
```

Comment: Suggestion/Hint.  Since you are starting at the top of the document, you are always pushing stuff down.  Try to start at the END of the document and search BACKWARDS.  This way, when you find something, you are already covering from that point forward and just keep pushing down.  At least that is now done and you wont be overstepping that which you just added.

Comment: @DRapp Sorry mate. I don't know how to do it. When you add a line to the page from the last and subsequent ones, a shift will occur. I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original suggestion by working backwards ended up *not* working as anticipated.  Because each page adding a new line would force extra lines and keep pushing data down, so where an original page end new one start *was*, could not be pushed yet even more.  So, starting from the top of the document and moving forward was more effective such as...

At the top of your code, I added this as a *using* context so you can use the shorthand name of *WordAutomation* instead of the longer *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word* as you will see in the function.

```
using WordAutomation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
protected void TestWordAuto()
{
    // I just sampled with a bogus Word Document with some text
    // in it and put on my desktop, you can obviously change
    var wordSampleFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TestAuto1.docx");

    // Create an instance of a word, make it visible to see
    // what is happening throughout if you want to, and
    // open / activate the file
    var wrd = new WordAutomation.Application();
    wrd.Visible = true;
    wrd.Documents.Open(wordSampleFile);
    wrd.ActiveDocument.Activate();

    // Object handle to active document
    var holdMainDoc = wrd.ActiveDocument;

    // Get a "Selection" object of the current document
    var sel = wrd.Selection;

    // Now, we can do a loop through all the pages starting at the end
    var lastPageNumber = 1;
    do
    {
        // Go to the top of each page
        sel.GoTo(WordAutomation.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WordAutomation.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToNext, null, lastPageNumber);

        // Insert some text
        sel.TypeText($"Some Text At top of page {lastPageNumber}\r");

        // Add to page counter loop in document
        lastPageNumber++;
        // Keep going until the page number we just finished
        // was the last page in the document.
    } while (lastPageNumber < holdMainDoc.Words.Last.Information[WordAutomation.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber]);

    MessageBox.Show("Finished");
}
```

Comment: Hello. I try use code...but ...last page dont.

Comment: @profpow, try changing the WHILE clause to <=

Comment: Yes. All document ) Why is it shifting to the previous page?<https://pastenow.ru/89307efa091d66b467e50d276e788f09>

Comment: @profpow, I cant answer what specific issue you are encountering.  You have a document and keep looking to insert text at the top of each page.  This will thus push the end content and possibly keep expanding the final page count.  I provided a significant option that appeared to mostly work.  Without specific context of what is failing, how large your document is that needs additional page extensions, I dont know how to answer.  Have you tried stepping through the debugging to see how / where these last page being worked on vs final are failing?

Comment: ok. Thank you very much! Will tryning doing!